# DSA, RSA, ECDSA etc - which one is cheapest for signing?

Tags: rsa, signature, dsa

For a protocol where the server presents its signature to prove authenticity (e.g. IKE/SIGMA/STS with only one party authenticated), it's essential that the signing is extremely cheap, while verification can be almost arbitrarily expensive.

RSA appears to be the worst alternative, but what about DSA vs. ECDSA? Is there some other signing algorithm that could be even better (i.e. consume even less CPU to calculate)?

Comment: ECDSA is rather cheap. Personally I'd go with Ed25519 for signatures, which has a easily available high performance implementations.

Comment: But I don't really like using signatures for transport encryption since it weakens deniability. I prefer EC-Diffie-Hellman, even though it's more expensive than signing.

Comment: @CodesInChaos What do you mean? Signing is not used for encrypting data in SIGMA/STS.

Comment: I mean that I don't like using signatures to authenticate a side in a transport security protocol, like TLS. I prefer using DH for that. DH is a bit slower, but it offers stronger deniability.

Comment: @CodesInChaos what sort of scheme do you propose?

Comment: RSA decryption as used in RSA TLS suites authenticates. Or the DH approach [CurveCP](http://curvecp.org) and [Noise](https://github.com/trevp/noise/wiki) take. In either case you only prove possession of the private key to the party you're communicating with, not to everybody.

Comment: @CodesInChaos the downside of RSA decryption is that it is heavy on the server CPU - and gets much worse the bigger the key. This is what I'm currently using, but I'm not particularly happy about it. If you look at the SIGMA protocol there's a version which uses DH to set up the encryption keys, and the signed authentication response is then sent over the encrypted channel. This means ECDH or DH for the key exchange and some freely chosen signature function for authentication.

Comment: If you rotate your ECDH key only once a minute and use it for multiple connections, you need only one signature per minute. i.e. the only costly operation is ECDH. Or you can sign each time, one EC signature has half the cost of ECDH.

Comment: @CodesInChaos It's ECDH/DH + signing in SIGMA. How would you get around signing with just ECDH/DH?

Answer (score 6):

From these three, ECDSA is faster - it does arithmetic with smaller numbers, and is thus faster. (RSA verification is faster than ECDSA, even though it uses larger numbers, because it computes a exponentiation by a small number.)

Still, elliptic curve [Schnorr signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature) should be around 5-10% faster than ECDSA (or even more in a side-channel resistant implementation) since it does not require an inversion modulo the curve order. And as mentioned, there is also Ed25519, which uses a special, non-standard curve in order to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The BLS pairing based signature requires only one exponentiation, and verification requires a pairing computation. However, it can only sign group elements, and hashing to them is a bit painful.

Comment: ECDSA should be faster than BLS, since it can use a special prime for the finite field arithmetic. And if you need short sigatures, Zhang/Safavi-Naini/Susilo should be faster than BLS since it uses a fixed point multiplication.